# Query inside a form field in MS Acce

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables `groups` and `genres`. They look like this:

```
GROUPS:
    grp_id
    grp_name
    genre_id
GENRES:
    genre_id
    genre_name
```

`genre_id` fields from the two tables form a link.

I'm trying to create a form and a report with descriptions on entities from `groups`, but I have to get the `genre_name` field from the other table instead of just printing its ID.
Is it possible to get the form field to display a field from the second table?

So far I've only managed to display all field of `groups` table, but I need something similar to

```
SELECT genres.genre_name
FROM genres, groups
WHERE groups.grp_name = !!current_group_name!!
      AND genres.genre_id = groups.genre_id
```

Comment: This is what a `JOIN` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you wanted the `genre_name` for each record in the `GROUPS` table, you can do:

```
SELECT genres.genre_name
FROM genres 
INNER JOIN groups 
ON genres.genre_id = groups.genre_id;
```

This joins on the field they have in common (1:M relationship I am assuming).

If you also need a join on group name, you can add `genres.genre_name = groups.grp_name` as well.

Let me know if this gives you the desired results.

Comment: I know how to do this under normal conditions. The problem is that I must create forms and reports (university assignment), and I can't understand how to include queries like this in a form field.

Comment: You can save your query, and use it as the record source for your form. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-query-as-the-record-source-for-a-form-or-report-e54251f3-57ca-4a7d-8e77-e498966cd41b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: That's exactly the thing I've been looking for! Thank you.

Comment: @fwiffo No problem. Sorry I had misinterpreted your question